# AWS chmod 400 pem: No such file or directory problem

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Hi there I struggle with AWS EC2 on Mac terminal. Of course at first I tried as many possibilities as I could. I read and applied almost everything which I found. At first I want to tell you that I made step by step in amazon web and I stocked just here at this phrase.

```
chmod 400 myApp.pem
```

and then throws error "No such file or directory"

I tried different combos I got this file on my desktop and in download files. I tried both and nothing work properly. I don't know where is problem, but I can see that is big problem.

Answer (score 0):

in my case was key download from AWS wich looks like keyPair.pem.tex rename and just follow the flow :D